# Discord.js v14 interaction failed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Receiving an error: this interaction failed, none of my console logs are outputting besides the "logged in as". I have given the bot the correct token as well as permissions for admin, bot, and application.commands

here is my index.js file

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Events } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
    ]
})


client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

const options = [
    '',
    'https://media.giphy.com/media/wJZTbXayokOgbCfyQe/giphy.gif',
    'https://media.giphy.com/media/QXh9XnIJetPi0/giphy.gif',
    '',
];

client.on(Events.MessageCreate, message => {
    console.log(message);
});

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, interaction => {
    console.log(`test1`);
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
        console.log(`test3`);
    if (interaction.commandName === 'hugging-face') {
        console.log(`test3`);
         interaction.reply(
             options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)]
        );
    }
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "discord-slash-bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "package install",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "register": "node -r dotenv/config discord-slash-bot/register.js",
    "start": "node -r dotenv/config index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "discord.js",
    "@discordjs/rest",
    "discord-api-types",
    "dotenv"
  ],
  "author": "conner",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/rest": "^1.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.3",
    "discord-api-types": "^0.37.28",
    "discord.js": "^14.7.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3"
  }
}
```

Here is my register.js to register the commands

```
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const commands = [
    {
        name: 'hugging-face',
        description: 'input images and prompt',
    },
];

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

        await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(process.env.APP_ID), {
            body: commands,
        });

        console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Please add the full error stack, it gives more context and helps us understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what the issue was, but it seems like register.js isn't running if there aren't any logs and/or was run before changes were made. I would run:

`npm install && npm run register && npm run start`

'npm install' would reinstall your dependencies, in case it's a versioning issue, while

'npm run register' would run ./discord-slash-bot/register.js to refresh all of the commands.

Hope this helps; cheers!